# Where is the @AuthorizedFeignClient in Jhipster Release 3.11.0?

Tags: jhipster

I have setup my Jhipster Uaa server, gateways and others micro services and i want to use @AuthorizedFeignClient annotation for inter-service-communication as well explained here : https://jhipster.github.io/using-uaa/

But i cannot find it into the java source generated(Jhispter Release 3.11.0).

Did i have to copy manually in my project this only 2 classes found in jhispter github generator for the moment ? (because still in beta ?) :
.../client/_AuthorizedFeignClient.java
and
.../client/_OAuth2InterceptedFeignConfiguration.java

Thanks,

Francois

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currently the `@AuthorizedFeignClient` annotation is only available for microservice applications using UAA as authentication type, but not for gateways and UAA server itself!

I guess you were looking for the annoation in the gateway, or the the UAA server.

Why is this like this? For the gateway it is because the gateway already has a couple of responsibilities, so building composite logic in there is not a good idea.

If you generate a microservice (not gateway, not uaa server), you should have the client package in your Java root with this annoatation, as well as some more configurations (feign client config, load balanced resource details...)
You can copy those to your gateway, to make it working there.

You can copy them to the UAA, too. More on that, this even will work, but with some weird fact...when UAA will ask service "foo" for some data, it will first ask the UAA for a client credentials authentication....like performing a query to itself...while it could just access grant it itself. There is no accurate way to do it, but I didn't want to keep it in this uncool way in JHipster, so the annotation is for microservice only.

Comment: Indeed i was  in the UUA server and a gateway ! I succeed to had this functionality to gateway and UUA too :). Thanks you.

Comment: I agree this is quite a weird design to do. In fact, i planned to have 2 gateways ( front end and back end) and i wanted the uua server (or the front end gateway) to call the backend gateway or microservice. When front end user register is ok and confirmed, it will call automatically another registration backend (hyperledger/fabric-cop for instance ;) ).

Comment: i am not really sure about what you are doing or want to do. However the gateway automatically creates routes for the microservice, so you can reach every service this by accessing its url. The feign client is intended, if one service want to consume another service directly, without going over gateway, and still authenticed